# Git - Merging develop into master causes major conflicts when it shouldn't?

Tags: git, merge, git-flow

I am a little confused as to whats happened to my branches.

The process I have been following for a release are:

Create release branch off of develop when ready for release.

Test release branch

Any bugs that are fixed during this time are merged into the release branch and into develop

When release is ready I merge the release branch into master.  At this point master has everything for the release and everything that is in develop apart from any new features added after the release branch was made.

However, any time I want to merge release into master I got a plethora of conflicts.  But I thought that merging into master would just overwrite anything in master since these are the latest changes.

So I had to take all changes from the release branch OVER the conflict from the master branch to finish the merge.

Now any time I change a file in develop and then try merge into master I get a conflict.  Its like the master branch doesn't realise that the code in develop came after or something.

How can I fix this?

In dev ops  it states that my master branch is 100 commits behind develop (which is correct as there have been changes since that release) but that it is 2 ahead of develop.  The two commits ahead of develop are the merge commits from the release branches into master.  Do I need to merge master into develop so develop has those to commits even though there would be no file changes?

Comment: What makes you think it shouldn't have conflicts?

Comment: @evolutionxbox because the files in master haven't been changed.  There were no commits to master.  Therefore I thought the merge of the release branch would just merge straight into master without conflicts but to my surprise there were.

Comment: So if the files haven't changed, what are the conflicts?

Comment: The conflicts are on files that have changed in develop.  Master doesn't have the latest code, so when I merge in develop I expect develops changes to apply onto master.  But its complaining that there is a merge conflict in master on many of the files even though those files havent changed

Comment: So the files have been changed? Merging `release` into `master`, where `release` has changed files from `develop`? Conflicts are expected. The solution is to resolve them. This is a fundamental part of using git.

Comment: Release was ahead of master.

Master had no changes at all.

When I merge release into master I expect there to be no conflicts because there have been no changes in master.  Is this not reasonable?

Conflicts happen when a file has changed in branch a and branch b  and you are merging.  This isnt the case here.

Branch A (master) has no changes in it since we dont commit directly to master, there have been no hotfixes.

Branch B (release) has all the commits from the recent work.

When I merge B into A I dont expect there to be conflicts unless im missing something here?

Comment: Are you using [Git Flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/#diagram)? If yes, I don't think this sentence should ever happen without the in-between `release` branch you described: "Now any time I change a file in develop and then try merge into master I get a conflict." (Or did you mean when that commit on `develop` works its way into `master` via the `release` branch that you get the conflict?)

Comment: Regarding this statement: "Any bugs that are fixed during this time are merged into the release branch and into develop" How are those merges being done? Are the commits keeping the same IDs on both `release` and `develop`? If no, that could explain your issue.

Comment: @TTT yes its git flow essentially. 

(Or did you mean when that commit on develop works its way into master via the release branch that you get the conflict?) 

Sorry I didn't write that clearly.  When the commits that were on develop were merged into master (via the release branch) it caused the conflicts. 

So for all of them (except one actually) we created a hotfix branch off of release, fixed it there and merged it straight into release and develop so that they both had the fix.

Comment: @TTT The one that we done differently was:

There was work done on a feature branch (off of develop).  But this feature branch was ahead of develop so we couldnt just merge it into the release branch.  Therefore to get that work into the release we manually made the same changes to the release branch so that both develop and the release branch had the same changes.

Comment: It wont let me edit the above message but what I meant to say was:

"But this feature branch was ahead of the release branch" (it contained code from develop we hadn't tested in the release) so we didnt want to merge the feature branch directly into release.

Comment: @Barry got it. That makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

First off, I'm assuming you're using the documented [Git Flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/#diagram), or a close variant. If that's true, then:

**I agree with you that you should never have conflicts when merging `release` into `master`.**

So now let's try to figure out why you do have conflicts. The most likely cause would be at this step of your workflow:

> Any bugs that are fixed during this time are merged into the release branch and into develop

If you merge a bug fix branch into `release`, and then turn around and merge that same bug fix branch into `develop` **and if the commit IDs end up being different on each branch**, then you definitely could get conflicts later on when those commits on `develop` end up getting merged into `master`. Instead, if you merge a bug-fix into `release`, you should be merging the `release` branch back down into `develop`. If you're going to have conflicts you should have them at **that** merge, for example, if the same files you modified in that bug fix were also modified on `develop`.

As a rule of thumb, you should rarely ever merge the same branch into two shared branches. Instead, merge it into the higher branch first and then merge that branch down into the lower branch. For example, if you have a hotfix to production, merge the fix into `master`, and then merge `master` down to `release` if it exists, or `develop` if it doesn't. Or, if you have a bug fix to `release`, merge it in there and then merge `release` down to `develop`.

Sometimes this is unavoidable, for example if you make a fix on `develop` and then realize you need that in the existing `release` branch. (Or similarly if you put a bug fix on the `release` branch but then realize you need the fix in production *now*.) In that case you have no choice but to cherry-pick the fix into the higher environment, but then you should merge that change down to the lower environment right away and resolve the conflict right then.

If you follow this pattern all of your conflicts will only ever happen when merging `master` into `release` (or `master` into `develop` if you don't have a `release` branch), or when merging `release` into `develop`. You should never again have conflicts when merging `release` into `master`.

**Side Note:** when releasing to Prod, you don't have to merge the remainder of the `release` branch back into `develop`. Instead after merging `release` into `master` you can then merge `master` down to `develop`. This is slightly cleaner so that you don't have extra merge commits sitting on `master` that aren't in `develop` yet. Functionally it doesn't change anything. I, when using Git Flow, use this tactic because I like to see the tip commit of `master` is always on either `release` or `develop`, so that every merge of `release` into `master` could be a fast-forward merge, if you wanted it to. (Thus **proving** it would be impossible to have conflicts when merging `release` into `master`.)

Comment: Thanks for the overview.

So to get develop completely up to date and in sync with master I should merge master into develop right?  Then that should mean develop is in sync with master just that develop is ahead of master.  Since at the moment, master is behind develop by 100 commits (new work) but ahead of develop by 2 commits (the merges of the release branch into master).

Comment: @Barry yes. If you merge `master` into `develop` those 2 commits on `master` will get into `develop`, and from then on (if you don't currently have a `release` branch), you shouldn't have any conflicts from `release` into `master` again.

Comment: @Barry Just try to make sure the tip of `master` is always in `release` while `release` exists (which it will be if you follow the described strategy of merging down).

Comment: thanks. I merged master into develop today (there were no file changes because obviously everything in master was already in develop).  I thought that would mean they were in sync.  But as a test I then tried to merge develop into master (locally) and was faced with all the same conflicts again.  I dont understand why it thinks the same files are modified in master to create the conflict.

Comment: @Barry hmmm. I don't see how that's possible. If you merge `master` into `develop`, then that means the tip commit of `master` is in `develop`. If you then turn around and merge `develop` right back into `master` it isn't possible to have conflicts there, unless new commits appeared on `master`. You mentioned "locally" for `develop` into `master` but not necessarily for the other merge. Are your local branches up to date, or, is it possible your local `develop` or local `master` has diverged from origin?

Comment: I dont think they have diverged from origin no  as when I do a git pull it states im already  up to date and git status shows everything is fine.  Even if I do the merge within dev ops itself it shows conflicts.

Comment: @Barry so where did you merge `master` into `develop`?

Comment: I done the merge via a pull request in dev ops.  Master into develop then took all changes from develop.

Comment: @Barry something doesn't seem right. If you merged `master` into `develop` in "dev ops" (Azure DevOps?), then the tip of `master` should be in `develop`. You can confirm by running: `git fetch` to make sure you have the latest, and then  `git merge-base origin/develop origin/master`. The output of that commit should be the same as the tip commit of `master`, which you can see with: `git rev-parse origin/master`. If they're equal, then turning around and merging `develop` back into `master` in Azure DevOps *could* be fast-forward and by definition can't have conflicts.

Comment: thanks for the help.  When I do the `merge-base` command I get a commit that I done back in August?   When I do the `rev-parse` command I get the commit I completed to merge the release into master.   Not sure what  the first command is doing specifically but they are not the same commit?

Comment: @Barry the point of the first command was to make sure that the tip of `origin/master` (the output of the `rev-parse` command) is in `origin/develop`. You said you merged `master` into `develop` on the remote server (is it Azure DevOps?), so it should be there. It doesn't appear that it is, at least not in your copy of *that* repo where you did the merge.

Comment: @Barry It's been a long time since we discussed this, but I was just rereading these comments and it occurred to me that maybe you didn't do a regular merge in Azure DevOps when you merged `master` into `develop`? Perhaps you selected a different merge type such as squash, rebase fast-forward, or semi-linear merge (aka rebase merge)?